# External css is not getting applied in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using external stylesheet for react code. It is not working. I have five files in my VS react code. index.html, index.js, AppC.js, AppC.css, UserC.js Except index.html all other files are in src. I am not getting any error only thing css is not getting applied.( I did not change index.html) (Is it okay to change App.js file name as  AppC.js or something else? I know we can not change index.html and index.js)

```
**index.js**

import AppC from './AppC'
import UsersC from './UsersC'
ReactDOM.render(<AppC />,document.getElementById('root')); 

**AppC.js**

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './AppC.css';
import UsersC from './UsersC';


export default class AppC extends Component {
    render(){
        let style = true;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h2 className= 'texg'> Hello Css </h2>
                <UsersC rang={style ? 'textg' : 'textb' } />
            </React.Fragment>      
              );
    }
}

**AppC.css**


.txtg{
    color:green;
}
.txtb{
    color:blue;
}

**UserC.js**


import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class UsersC extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h3 className={this.props.rang}> from heading  </h3>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you you have any css rules that would apply to your DOM.  `texg` is the only class, and there's not css rule for it.

Comment: Your class name is `textg` but in css you used `txtg`

Comment: Which CSS doesn't apply? green one or blue one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `texg` to `txtg`

```
 <React.Fragment>
      <h2 className= 'texg'> Hello Css </h2>
        //To
       <h2 className= 'txtg'> Hello Css </h2>
      <UsersC rang={style ? 'textg' : 'textb' } />
  </React.Fragment>
```